# Extraction of data from a file if pattern matches in Python

Tags: python

In a file that holds data:

```
startTc:TC9

Client-1
IPAddress:10.203.205.111
Port:22
endTc:TC9

------------------------------------------------
startTc:TC5
Client-2
IPAddress of Client-2:10.203.205.112
Port:23
endTc:TC5
------------------------------------------------
```

if condition of `startTc:TC5` matches then data of

```
Client-2
IPAddress of Client-2:10.203.205.112
Port:23
```

needs to be extracted like 23 in Port:
and file reading needs to be closed when it sees `endTc:TC5`

Comment: Client 2 , IPAddress of Client-2 are in diffrent lines in a file

Comment: Please *edit* your question to reflect the real format of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using regex,in following pattern i use [positive look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the string between `startTc:TC5\n` and `\nendTc:TC5`, then you can split your result with `\n`:

```
>>> s="""startTc:TC9
... 
... Client-1
... IPAddress:10.203.205.111
... Port:22
... endTc:TC9
... 
... ------------------------------------------------
... startTc:TC5
... Client-2
... IPAddress of Client-2:10.203.205.112
... Port:23
... endTc:TC5
... ------------------------------------------------"""
>>> re.search(r'(?<=startTc:TC5\n).*(?=\nendTc:TC5)',s,re.DOTALL).group(0).split('\n')
['Client-2', 'IPAddress of Client-2:10.203.205.112', 'Port:23']
```

Note that if you want to read this string from file you need to use `open('file_name').read()` instead `s` in `re.search` function.

Comment: Thanks, But what does s mean in 
re.search(r'(?<=startTc:TC5\n).*(?=\nendTc:TC5)',s,re.DOTALL).group(0).split('\n')

Comment: @Anil welcome, its the string! checkout the edit for explain!

Comment: regular expression works well and thanks much. Only issue now I am facing is sometimes input is startTc:x and endTc:x and other time it is startTc:y and endTc:y

Answer (score 0):

```
def getData(infilepath, start, end):
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        data = []
        answer = []
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line: continue
            if line == start or data:
                data.append(line)
            if line == end:
                temp = dict(data[1].split('-'))
                temp['ip'] = data[2].split(":")[1]
                temp['port'] = data[3].split(":")[1]
                answer.append(temp)
                data = []
    return answer
```

Usage:

```
data = getData("path/to/file", "startTc:TC5", "endTc:TC5")
for d in data:
    print("Client:", d['Client'])
    print("IP:", d['ip'])
    print("Port:", d['port'])
```